# HTTP Errors while consuming non-WCF Web Service using a WCF Client

Tags: wcf

I am trying to consume a third party web service, which is developed not in .NET but in some other langauge (may be in Java). I am trying to consume the service from WCF Client. But while adding Service reference it is throwing a error:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'basic realm="EXTRACT-CREDENTIAL"'.

Also when I am hitting the service URL in a browser it's throwing an error as follows:

> HTTP GET Requests are not supported by the broker. Please use HTTP POST instead

What could be the way to consume the service from WCF client?

Comment: The error message seem quite informative; what have you tried so far to fix them?